# How do I use gnuplot to plot some simple X0,Y0 X1,Y1 data?

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data that is a series of endpoints for the lines in `x0, y0, x1, y1` format.

for example :

```
 x0    y0    x1    y1
-----------------------    
 1.0,  1.1,  2.0,  1.0

 2.0,  1.0,  2.0,  2.0

 2.0,  2.0,  1.0,  2.0

 1.0,  2.0,  1.0,  1.0
```

I don't need any axis data, text titles, or page numbers. I can scale the data up or down or add a fixed offset if required.

How would I convert this data to a file that can be printed on a sheet of 8.5 x 11 paper?

Comment: @tames: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have reformatted your question, hope you agree with my changes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to plot a rectangle from `(1,1)` to `(2,2)`, and remove all the axes etc.?

The easiest way is probably something like this:

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
set yrange [0:3]
set xrange [0:3]
set obj 1 rect from 1,1 to 2,2
plot NaN notitle
```

I am assuming that the first `1.1` is a typo.  Otherwise you can plot individual lines:

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset border
set yrange [0:3]
set xrange [0:3]
set style arrow 1 nohead
set arrow from 1,1.1 to 2,1 as 1
set arrow from 2,1 to 2,2 as 1
set arrow from 2,2 to 1,2 as 1
set arrow from 1,2 to 1,1 as 1
plot NaN notitle
```

Comment: How to plot line segment with labels (assuming we have a fifth column Label) ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is in a file called 'data.dat', probably the simplest way to draw the line segments indicating their direction (this may or may not be wanted, in which case there is also probably a formatting option to the *with vectors* plotting option although I don't know what it is off-hand) would be the following,

```
plot [0:3][0:3] 'data.dat' u 1:2:($3-$1):($4-$2) notitle with vectors
```

as Alok indicated in his post, the axes of the plot can be removed with the unset commands he used

```
unset xtics; unset ytics; unset border
```

This will generate a plot that looks like the following,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes, the '1.1' was a typo, it should have been '1.0'  The plot that I want to draw is not necessarily going to be a square or rectangle. I just chose the first values that came to mind.

I'm still curious how I can generate a 'printable' file, ie in jpg or bmp format.

Comment: @tames: look at `set term` - particularly `set term jpeg`, `set term post`, etc.  For postscript, you can say `set term post portrait size 8.5 11` for letter paper in portrait orientation.  Look at `help set term` and `help set out` for more.

Comment: How to plot line segment with labels (assuming we have a fifth column Label) ?